# Why would removing a couple of modules remove lots of packages?

Tags: apt, uninstall, dependencies

I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

Why would that command do the following and what's the best way to undo it?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  couchdb-common erlang-asn1 erlang-base-hipe erlang-crypto erlang-eunit
  erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-public-key
  erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools
  erlang-webtool erlang-xmerl gtk2-engines libbit-vector-perl
  libcarp-clan-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl
  libclass-method-modifiers-perl libcommon-sense-perl
  libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libdata-random-perl
  libdate-calc-perl libdate-calc-xs-perl libenet2a libextutils-depends-perl
  libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libgd-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl
  libgnome2-wnck-perl libgoo-canvas-perl libgoocanvas-common libgoocanvas3
  libgtk2-appindicator-perl libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl
  libgtkimageview0 libhttp-server-simple-perl libjs-prototype
  libjs-scriptaculous libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libmouse-perl
  libmozjs185-1.0 libpath-class-perl libproc-processtable-perl
  libproc-simple-perl libsctp1 libsort-naturally-perl libtie-ixhash-perl
  libunique-1.0-0 libx11-protocol-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl lksctp-tools
  perlmagick supertuxkart-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libxml-libxml-perl
The following packages will be REMOVED
  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-yahoo aisleriot apt-transport-https apturl
  atom ca-certificates checkbox-gui checkbox-ng checkbox-ng-service
  chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n compiz compiz-gnome couchdb
  couchdb-bin curl darktable deja-dup-backend-gvfs evolution-data-server
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 git
  gnome-contacts gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-share
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gvfs-backends
  indicator-applet kerneloops-daemon libbonoboui2-0 libcmis-0.4-4 libcurl3
  libcurl3-gnutls libflickcurl0 libfolks-eds25 libgconf2-4 libgdata13
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnome2-gconf-perl
  libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libldap-2.4-2 libldb1
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailutils4 libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-dropbox-api-perl libnet-oauth-perl liboauth0 libpanel-applet-4-0
  libpurple0 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-writer libruby1.9.1
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libslv2-9 libsmbclient libspice-server1
  libwww-mechanize-perl libwww-perl libxml-parser-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl
  libxml-twig-perl mailutils mythes-en-us nautilus-share network-manager-gnome
  oneconf oneconf-common postfix python-cupshelpers python-gconf python-gnome2
  python-httplib2 python-ldb python-oneconf python-piston-mini-client
  python-pycurl python-requests python-samba python-smbc
  python-ubuntu-sso-client python3-checkbox-ng python3-httplib2
  python3-oneconf python3-piston-mini-client python3-pycurl python3-requests
  python3-software-properties python3-uno redshift ruby ruby1.9.1
  samba-common-bin samba-libs seahorse shutter smbclient software-center
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk spotify-client steam-launcher supertuxkart
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev telepathy-haze transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-qt unity unity-lens-photos
  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-musicstores vlc vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-pulse whoopsie xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-qxl
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libxml-libxml-perl
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 151 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
Need to get 337 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,072 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies

A lot of those packages depend on a package called `ubuntu-desktop`.

Now you've not chosen to remove that - it's not in this list:

```
postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

but note the package `ca-certificates`.

I ran this command:

```
apt-cache rdepends postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

and it gives me a list, like this:

```
postfix
Reverse Depends:
 |ubumirror
  postfix-policyd-spf-python
  postfix:i386
  ...
mailutils
Reverse Depends:
  heirloom-mailx:i386
  bsd-mailx:i386
  ...
libsasl2-2
Reverse Depends:
  libvirt0
  libvirt-bin
  mutt-patched
  libkmanagesieve4
  libkldap4
  libkimap4
  ...
ca-certificates
Reverse Depends:
  google-chrome-unstable
  google-chrome-stable
  google-chrome-beta
  ubuntu-touch
  ...
  ubuntu-desktop
  ...
libsasl2-modules
Reverse Depends:
  xubuntu-desktop
  ubuntustudio-desktop
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  sendmail-bin
  ...
```

`ca-certificates` is important here, because `ubuntu-desktop` depends on it.

A lot of stuff needs `ubuntu-desktop`. A lot. If you remove those, a lot of stuff will break - so don't remove them. If you have to, don't remove `ca-certificates` - why were you trying to?

Comment: I suspected it is `ca-certificates` but gave a more general answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I saw and plus oned!

Comment: Was running through a tutorial for sending emails and decided to do it another time - wanted to tidy up so wanted to remove the packages it installed.  Thanks for the info @Tim.  Would upvote but lacking in rep - suspect my rep will reduce after this ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because remove of some of that packages break dependecies of other packages.

You better not agree with that removal.

If you already removed all that, you can restore it by

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But there is no guarantee, that everything is restored.

You can look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see what has been removed.
Then install missing packages.

But `ubuntu-desktop` should pull most of them if not all.

In your specific case **DO NOT REMOVE *ca-certificates***

Comment: Why don't you accept it then ;-). Press "bird" at the left.